# Debian stuck at blinking cursor after GNOME Display Manager started

Tags: debian

Just started using Linux for a week now so I'm kinda newbie here and little to no experience at coding but passionate to learn.

Temporarily my main computer will be unavailable, so I currently use an Intel Compute Stick with Windows 10 installed. Since I wanna learn Linux, I tried to live boot Debian 10 i586 (not sure maybe its i368) and it is stuck at the Debian logo.

So I rebooted the system, and pressed e at the GRUB, and replaced `splash quiet` to `nomodeset`.

The linux kernel log (*if that's what called at the stream of text with green ok texts and logs some things that started*) going smoothly, until it went to:

`[  OK  ] Started GNOME Display Manager.`

After this appeared, the blinking cursor appeared at the top. The logs didn't dissapear, it was behind the logs if it's even relevant.

The ttys are available but I don't know what to do afterwards. Searched thru the web and the answers were either not the answer to my question, the answers were too complicated for a week old Linux user like me, or I just didn't understand.

I tried:
`$ startx`
`$ xauth`
`# service gdm start`

Thanks for the help, and sorry If I typed some unethical things, this is the first time I will post in Stack.

Comment: *Debian 10 i586 (not sure maybe its i368)*  That might be relevant, so you should make sure. The "normal" PC nowadays would need `amd64` instead. Maybe you can simply try that iso?

Comment: It was i686 after typing ```lscpu``` on the terminal, so its maybe because of wrong iso, thanks for the help